# SpringBoot OAuth2: Purpose of the .secret() function?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm currently learning about SpringBoots OAuth2.0 implementation and I came across the following tutorial: http://www.tinmegali.com/en/2017/06/25/oauth2-using-spring/.

It contains this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
           .withClient("trusted-app")
           .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
           .authorities("ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
           .scopes("read", "write")
           .resourceIds(resourceId)
           .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
           .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
           .secret("secret");
}
```

I have looked all over the internet for documentation on the `secret` function, but I simply cannot find what it does, including on the official SpringBoot API reference. All I can say for certain is it takes a `string` parameter.

What exactly does the `secret()` function do in the snippet above? What does SpringBoot do with the parameter of this function?

Comment: You should upvote the answer as well for fellow users of stackoverflow. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`secret()`** actually stands for `client_secret`. When you are going to issue a token, your request should be authorize by server. hence `client_id` and `client_secret` for authorization. In your `http` request you should send the `client_id` and `client_secret` in `http` headers (probably in base64 format). Its called **Basic Authorization**. And for authentication you need to send username and password.

Probably you should send in `http` header something like that (Basic: "`base64` value of your `client_id` and `client_secret`")

```
"Authorization":"Basic dHJ1c3RlZC1hcHA6c2VjcmV0"
```

If you are using postman then your token endpoint will `http://host:port/contextPath/oauth/token` and request herder will be 
[image]

If you click the Headers tab then you see how your `client_id` and `secret` converted in `base64` format. In request body you should send **`grant_type`:`password`** for token as a key value pair.